# Uncaught TypeError: querySelector is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

Getting a really strange JS error.

I'm using isotope.js to filter items via some filter buttons and a search field like in [this example](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mCdbD).

My use case is slightly different as I'm looking to search the contents of a specific child element within the parent and not the whole element. I've made some edits to the example code to suit my needs and convert it to vanilla JS so my version of the initialisation looks like this:

```js
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;

var iso = new Isotope('.gridListing', {
    itemSelector: '.gridItem',
    percentPosition: true,
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    stagger: 30,
    filter: function(itemElem) {
        var name = itemElem.querySelector('.name').textContent;
        const searchResult = qsRegex ? text.match(qsRegex) : true;
        const buttonResult = buttonFilter ? itemElem.classList.contains(buttonFilter) : true;
        return searchResult && buttonResult;
    },
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
  }
});
```

This code works absolutely fine in my local environment which is running using WebPack. When I compile the code and copy across to my live site running a WordPress install I get the following error message.

*"Uncaught TypeError: itemElem.querySelector is not a function"*

I'm not sure what would cause the code to run fine locally but fail on a live server. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be hugely helpful.

Comment: My best guess quickly looking at this would be that `itemElem` is not what you think it is the first time the code is run. So `querySelector` simply isn't a function on _whatever `itemElem` is_ at the time

Comment: Log the value of itemElem. No sense in guessing.

Comment: You're right, I removed the filter function and replaced with console.log(itemElem). On my local install this returns the expected elements but on the live environment this returns 0.

Comment: Interesting. If you do a production build and run it locally, do you get the same result?

Comment: Production build returns the expected elements too. I thought it may to be do with elements not being loaded initially so moved the function inside a $(window).on('load) call but this didn't resolve the issue on the live site.

Comment: So, i know where the problem is coming from, but i'm not sure why it is affecting you. Basically, if jQuery exists, jquery's .is method is used, which would cause the answer below suggesting `index, item` to work. If jquery doesn't exist, a different function signature is used. Here is the code in question: https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/blob/master/js/isotope.js#L274

Comment: @KevinB Fixed! (sort of) the below solution doesn't work on my local environment but does work on the live environment. I can keep both blocks of code in for now and comment out the relevant one depending on if I'm working live or locally. It's not ideal but does the job. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

)
Try this filter block

```
filter: function(index, item) {
    var name = item.querySelector('.name').textContent;
    const searchResult = qsRegex ? text.match(qsRegex) : true;
    const buttonResult = buttonFilter ? item.classList.contains(buttonFilter) : true;
    return searchResult && buttonResult;
},
```

Comment: This gives me the error "Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined"

Comment: @MikeSmith Did you try it on live? i'm betting it works live and not dev. :)

Comment: This failed on my local environment but works for the live environment so marking as the answer. Thanks for the help.